# SpringBoot - Entity propagation for relationships

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot, api

I have two entities: WorkoutTemplate and ConcreteExercise.

In WorkoutTemplate I have this relationship with ConcreteExercises

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "belongingWorkout", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ConcreteExercise> concreteExercises;
```

And in ConcreteExercise I have this relationship with WorkoutTemplate

```
@ManyToOne
private WorkoutTemplate belongingWorkout;
```

I would like to insert a WorkoutTemplate into my database...
I make the request to the controller sending a Json like this:

```
{ "workoutName" : "My Workout",
concreteExercises: [
   {
"name" : "Squat"
   } 
 ]
}
```

The DAO insert into my DB the WorkoutTemplate
And insert also in the table of the ConcreteExercise the name.
But not the reference to the WorkoutTemplate...
Practically, the table ConcreteExercise is made of:

```
id, name, belongin_workout_id
```

With the request above, we populate the id (auto-increment) and the name, but not the foreign key to the WorkoutTemplate.

How can I solve this ?
I would like to automatically insert the foreign key without sending it in the request or doing it manually into the service

Answer (score 1):

Hi there it's because you are not using **@JoinColumn** which marks a column for as a join column for an entity association or an element collection.

On your **WorkoutTemplate** entity - you can retain this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "belongingWorkout", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ConcreteExercise> concreteExercises;
```

But on your **ConcreteExercise** entity - you need to have this change:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workout_template_id", nullable = false)
private WorkoutTemplate belongingWorkout;
```

The above code will create a foreign key linking the **ConcreteExercise** entity with the primary key from the **WorkoutTemplate** entity. The name of the foreign key column in the **ConcreteExercise** entity is specified by `name` property which for this case is **workout_template_id** - feel free to change this.

If you have set this up but still not working, it will also be helpful to share a code snippet on how are you saving these.

Comment: Yes, but in this way I have to send the workoutID into the ConcreteExercise in the request ... otherwise it throws the exception Column 'workout_template_id' cannot be null

Comment: I would like to automatically insert the workoutID into the concreteExercise, once I insert the WorkoutTemplate, because I cannot know the ID and put it in the request before inserting the WorkoutTemplate. This process should be automatically done

Comment: If you could share your code snippet on how you are doing this anyways, looking into your request you are passing the name of the workout right? So on your service, you can get the workout by a **findByName** repository call then from there you can now do this -> `ConcreteExercise newExercise = new ConcreteExercise()`; then `foundWorkoutByName.getConcreteExercises().add(newExercise)`. But you have to be careful on the performance of finding **WorkoutTemplate** by name instead of its primary key ID. You need to index it for faster search by making it **Unique**.